# jQuery object unexpected behaviour

Tags: jquery

My code is available below, and here: http://jsfiddle.net/fRpCy/

```
var input = [];
input.push($('input'));

$(input).live('keydown', function (event) {
    console.log('You have pressed a key!');
});
```

I would expect this code to respond to keypresses in the console. For some reason, it doesn't. What is the problem with this code? (Note: I know how to fix it, I just don't know what is wrong with it!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is expecting the `$()` function to take an array of jQuery objects as an argument.  You essentially have this:

```
$([$('input')])
```

Per [this jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), I don't think it supports that.  The jQuery function will take:

- a selector string
- an element
- an element array
- a jQuery object
- some HTML
- a function

Important to note is that it will NOT take an array of jQuery objects.  An element array is not the same thing as a jQuery object array, though you can obtain an element array from a jQuery object with the `makeArray()` method if you really wanted to.

There are several alternatives that would work:

The simplest is to not save any intermediary value:

```
$('input').live('keydown', function (event) {
    console.log('You have pressed a key!');
});
```

---

This one gets an actual DOM element into the input array so the input array is a type of array that the jQuery function supports (though I can think of no reason to actually use this code):

```
var input = [];
input.push($('input').get(0));

$(input).live('keydown', function (event) {
    console.log('You have pressed a key!');
});
```

---

Or, if there are multiple input values, just save the jQuery object for future use:

```
var inputs = $('input');

inputs.live('keydown', function (event) {
    console.log('You have pressed a key!');
});
```

---

Or, if you want an element array, you can get that like this:

```
var input = $('input').makeArray();

$(input).live('keydown', function (event) {
    console.log('You have pressed a key!');
});
```

---

Or, if what you really have is an array of jQuery objects and you want to combine those together into a new single jQuery object, this is one way to do that:

```
// var input is an array of jQuery objects you already have

var allElements = [];   // new empty array of DOM elements
// iterate over array of jQuery objects getting array of DOM elements from each
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    allElements = allElements.concat($.makeArray(input[i]));
}
$(allElements).live(...)
```

---

Or, a bit simpler way to do it:

```
var items = $.map(input, function(item, index) {return($.makeArray(item));});
$(items).live(...)
```

---

Or, now I've found the .add() method on a jQuery object:

```
var $items = input[0];                      // grab first jQuery object in array
for (var i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
    $items.add(input[i]);                   // add other ones onto it
}
$items.keydown(function() {...});
```

Incidentally, I'm finding the the array of DOM elements doesn't work with .live('keydown').  I don't know why.  It works with:

```
$(items).keydown(...)
```

And, since you have an array of DOM elements that already exist, there is no reason to use `.live()` anyway.  You can just use `.keydown()`.

jsFiddle working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qen2m/.

Comment: You aren't passing it an element array.  You are passing it a jQuery object array which is not the same thing.  An element array is an array of DOM elements.  See my recent edits to offer you several alternatives that are supported.

Comment: @jfriends: Thanks. But check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/fRpCy/1/ The `.autocomplete()` works fine, why shouldn't `.live()` also work?

Comment: Would you please either explain what you're really trying to accomplish here or use one of the documented and supported ways to pass objects to the jQuery function.  It seems silly to try to figure out why an undocumented method works in one case and not in another.  Stick to the supported mechanisms (of which there are plenty to use here) and you will not have this problem.  The jQuery function does not claim support for an array of jQuery objects as it's parameter.  Stop using it that way!  Use one of the zillion other ways that are supported.

Comment: Ok. Well I have an array of jQuery element. So how do I turn an array of jQuery element into a jQuery object with elements the elements of the array?

Comment: I added a way to do that to the end of my answer.  It would be better if you don't make the array of jQuery objects.  Just save an array of DOM elements instead because they are easier to merge.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm finding troubles with `.live('keydown')`.  But, I find it works when using the actual .keydown method instead of .live.

Comment: Aha. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need to add .each to iterate through the array of objects

```
jQuery.each(arr, function() {
  $(this).live('keydown', function (event) {
    console.log('You have pressed a key!');
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're creating an array (`var input`) which has a single element. Element 0 contains an array - returned by $('input') - because you almost certainly have multiple inputs on your page.

Can you try

```
$('input').live('keydown', function (event) {
    console.log('You have pressed a key!');
});
```

(untested)